# Alias a variable in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to declare an alias for a variable in Unity C#.
For example, in the following code:

```
struct Data
{
  int value;
}

class Instance
{
  private Data data;
  public int value => data.value;
}
```

The `=>` operator provides a **read-only** variable. I'm looking for a way to declare a variable that I can read **and** write to.
In C++ I would use the `using` keyword but that doesn't seem to work the same way in C#.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I advise you to read this documentation : [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: Why can't you use `property` ?

Comment: Something like C++ using keyword would be nicer in some cases, but yeah, properties are the only way C# provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`using` **directive**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) in `c#` (not to be confused with the [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) block) is used for having aliases for **TYPES** and **NAMESPACES** - not fields - e.g.

```
using BecauseICan = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;

public class Instance
{
    public BecauseICan x = new BecauseICan();
}
```

---

The `=>` is a read-only [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in ["expression body"](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#expression-body-definitions) notation and basically equals writing

```
// explicit getter but still as expression body
public int value
{
    get => data.value;
}
```

or also

```
// completely written out
public int value
{
    get
    {
        return data.value;
    }
}
```

As you can see it is simply the missing setter which makes it read-only.

So what speaks against using e.g.

```
// Note: I'm not sure if even possible but I guess it is not a good idea to call a property "value"
// "value" is a keyword within the property - see the setter

// again with expression body getter and setter
public int Value 
{ 
    get => data.value;
    set => data.value = value;
}
```

or also

```
// explicit written out
public int Value 
{ 
    get
    {
        return data.value;
    }
    set
    {
        data.value = value;
    }
}
```

---

Either way the `Data.value` needs to be `public` otherwise you can't access it from `Instance` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yeah I knew about the get and set keywords but not the shorthand using the => operator so thanks for that. I was picturing an operator as a shortcut for creating both a get and set, a '<=>' would be nice haha

Comment: @OwenMillward that would be cool indeed ^^ But the getter and setter can have way more complex bodies so probably no, this will never happen ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read,
> write, or compute the value of a private field.

```
//Just for sake of understanding I updated name of class and property
public class Student
{
  private Data data;
  public int RollNumber 
  {
     get { return data.value; }
     set {  data.value = value; }
  }

}
```

---

Now you can write/read the value of `RollNumber` property by,

```
Student instance = new Student();
instance.RollNumber= 123; //Assign 123 to Value
Console.WriteLine(instance.RollNumber); //Read value of property i.e 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property with a getter and setter on the private backing field.

You will also have to make sure that `value` is accessible (`internal`/`public`)

```
struct Data
{
    public int value;
}

public class Instance
{
    private Data data;
    public int value
    {
        get => data.value;
        set => data.value = value;
    }
}
```